# VSTS - Prevent commit to root path

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, build-definition

I'm trying to find a way to prevent files from being committed to the root of a repo. Couldn't find a way to do this via branch policies directly. Setting required reviewers on /* for example adds a group to any file being checked in to the repo. Is there a way to have a specific group/individual added as a reviewer if someone tries to check in a file **only** to the root(**/**) of the repo.

The only other option seems to be to add a build definition that runs a custom script to fail the build if a PR contains a file addition to root. Is there a vsts build task that might help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **PowerShell task** in your PR validation build definition to check if there has files in the root of the repo, the script as below:

```
$files=$(git ls-files)
echo $files
echo $files.length
for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Length; $i++)
{
  $file = $files[$i]
  if ($file -match "/")
  { echo "the file $file in subdir" }
  else
  { 
    echo "the file $file in root dir"
    exit 1
  }
}
```

Besides, you can use **pre-commit hook** in your local repo, so that you can detect if there has files to be committed in the root directory **before committing and pushing**. The script can be used for pre-commit hook as below:

```
#!/bin/sh

for sfile in $(git diff --name-only --cached)
do
{
  if [[ $sfile =~ "/" ]]; then
    echo "the file $sfile in subdir"
  else
    echo "the file $sfile in root, stop to commit!"
    exit 1
  fi
}
done
for ufile in $(git diff --name-only)
do
{
  if [[ $ufile =~ "/" ]]; then
    echo "the file $ufile in subdir"
  else
    echo "the file $ufile in root, stop to commit!"
    exit 1
  fi
}
done
```